# Make Title Float Over Content

Tags: css

[On this page](http://www.2touchrulz.com/courses/) I'm trying to make the title float over the content so that they are in line... I've tried to give the title similar CSS to the content as far as positioning is concerned. I'd be grateful for any tips!

Thanks guys,

Tara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is your `<img>` inside the `<head>` element of your document?

You should consider learning more about plain HTML/CSS before trying to make a WordPress website.

As proof of that fact:

```
<img class="title2" href="http://www.2touchrulz.com" src="/wp-content/themes/adventure/images/title2.png" />
```

Why does your `<img>` have an `href` attribute? You need:

```
<a href="http://www.2touchrulz.com/"><img .. /></a>
```

You can fix your title with only pure CSS changes like this:

```
img.title2 {
    width: 740px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -490px;
}
```

But, that's ***really*** not how you should be doing it.

You should forget the CSS I just wrote, and simply move the `<img>` to inside `<div id="center">`. Problem solved.

Comment: @thirtydot When I tried putting the img in the index.php file it didn't even show up on the page for some reason so I just thought I'd paste it in the head instead, and it worked that way, so I did it.

How would you suggest I learn better CSS & HTML? I find reading books about it pretty boring and learning by doing seems to me to be the best way...

So, would the correct code look like this: '<div id="center"><img etc. etc. /></div>'?

And where is the best place for me to put it?

Thank you,

Comment: @Tara: I agree, doing is learning - but you need a foundation. Try this site for good tutorials and reference: http://www.htmldog.com/

Comment: @thirtydot Thanks :) The href works now. I'm pretty new to this; I'm not a professional - I'm making this website as a favor for a non-profit.

Comment: @Tara: I second http://htmldog.com/ for tutorials. You need to make sure you're editing the right WordPress include file. It will probably be in a folder like `wp-content\themes\<yourtheme>`. You need to find the file in that folder that has `<div id="center>`, and insert your image inside and at the top of that `div`. It could well be called `index.php`. If you insert it in that correct file, it should show up.

Comment: @thirtydot Great! I found the div in index.php and it's working now :) Thank you very much